# QT parse timestamps from dates with microsecond precision

Tags: c++, qt, date, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to parse data files in xml format, where the time of the nodes is given as dates in the following format:

`2014-08-26T21:51:16.779947+02:00`

This would translate to:

`yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss.zzzzzz+UTC`

I have a start time in the given format and i need to get the relative times of all nodes relative to the starting time with microseconds precision.

QTime::fromString() only takes miliseconds. Is there an possibly easier extension than to write my own parser with my own time stamps?

I used boost libraries with self defined input facets

```
new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%s%ZP")));
```

However, I would prefer to include additional libraries only when absolutely necessary

Answer (score 0):

For the UTC I don t know how you can do but for the date and time , after you got split your string to get the date and the time, you can do something like this:

```
QString time("21:51:16.779");
QString date("2014-08-26");
QDate date = QDate::fromString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
QTime time = QTime::fromString(time, "h:m:s.zzz");
```

Indeed you can format the fromString for the date and time so you don t get only the miliseconds.

However, if you really want to get the microsecond, you should create a class which inherit to the QTime then overload the `void QTime::fromString(QString, QString);` method. Then in this method you will do something like that.

```
void MyTime::fromString(QString& str, QString format) {
 QRegExp rx("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{6})");
rx.indexIn(str);
_year = rx.cap(1);
_month = rx.cap(5);
_day = rx.cap(7);
_hour = rx.cap(9);
_min = rx.cap(11);
_sec = rx.cap(13);
_msec = rx.cap(15);
}
```

With  that, you should get the milli and microsecond in your msec. You should change the regex because it's not a perfect one but it should work. For the UTC see about the QTimeZone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

However, this does not solve the problem. I still cant parse the microsecond part of the time stamp.

Comment: Now you can get the microsecond.